# pstricks output garbled on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: pstricks, texlive, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and tried to recompile a pstricks document I had previously created on an older version of Ubuntu. However all the images came out wrong and consist of all the text contained in the image overlayed at a single position within the image. Lines and shapes are not rendered at all.

Trying the basic pstricks example also does not render correctly in the dvi.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5)
\psframe(0.7,2)(3.3,3)
\rput(2,2.5){First Example}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It just prints the text without the surrounding frame. I've tried uninstalling texlive and pstricks and reinstalling everything (using apt-get) to no avail.
I would appreciate any pointers as to how I can go about tracking down the issue.

Edit:
Solved thanks to JosephWright's answer.
At first I was compiling using the quickbuild option in texmaker with

```
latex -> view dvi
```

which gave the garbled output. I then tried

```
latex -> dvips -> view ps
```

That just hangs indefinitely so I started compiling using just latex and checking the dvi.

Using

```
latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf
```

works perfectly.

Comment: run the document with `xelatex`. Then you'll get a PDF output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, DVI viewers can't render PostScript (some do include code to do the conversion on-the-fly). Conversion to PostScript (or through to PDF) format is usually the best way to check on the correctness of the output: for me all is fine with the demo (TeX Live 2013).