# pstricks gives garbled output in TeXShop

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, texshop, auto-pst-pdf

I have a bunch of 3d images that I made using pstricks, but after I updated to Mavericks OS X 10.9.5 this summer the images no longer render properly.  All text (like axes labels) is stacked in the center of the image, and lines/graphs don't appear at all.  It seems identical to the problem in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128478/pstricks-output-garbled-on-ubuntu-13-04).

I am running the document with XeLaTeX, and have the typesetting set to TeX and DVI.  I made a file list using this MWE and a snippet of sample code from another thread:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

In the output the text appears on top of itself in the center of the page.  Here is the generated file list:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/05/19 v2.54a `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty    2014/05/09 v2.6d package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/05/09 v2.6d key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex    2014/05/19 v2.54a `PST-fp' (hv)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
xetex.def    2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2014/03/25 1.33 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
pst-pdf.sty    2008/10/09 v1.1v PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm still running Mavericks and I get what's probably expected. I don't think `auto-pst-pdf` is useful when XeLaTeX is used. Run TeX Live Utility and update everything, then retry.

Comment: @egreg:  Thanks for the comment.  I just went and updated all the packages in TeX Live, but unfortunately nothing has changed in the compiled document.

Comment: It might depend on the version of `ghostscript`.

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall the entire TeX distribution, which got me my images back.  But then, some of my documents are landscape format, so any images in the right hand column were cut off past the width of A4 paper.  I found a solution to that problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157216/xetex-pstricks-larger-page-size-is-cropped-to-a4). **However**, when I tried to edit `dvipdfmx.cfg` in TextWrangler, I couldn't save; I had to reinstall that as well with a version downloaded directly from Bare Bones.

It all took me a while, so I hope this helps someone out there.